# CountIf With Filtered Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was researching a way to count the number of zeroes in a column of data, even if the data gets filtered.  I found the following solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2:B18,ROW(B2:B18)-MIN(ROW(B2:B18)),,1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Pear",B2:B18))+0)
```

Where, `B2:B18` is the total list of data and `"Pear"` is the criteria being counted.

- Can someone explain how this formula is accomplishing this task?
- Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Your formula seems to be incomplete. It just ends in a comma. Could you review your notes and correct?

Comment: @nbayly `,` removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to determine that:

```
SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2:B18,ROW(B2:B18)-MIN(ROW(B2:B18)),,1))
```

is used to return an array of which cells are visible and hidden in the range.  1 is returned for visible and 0 is returned for hidden.

```
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Pear",B2:B18))+0)
```

is used to return an array of which cells contain `"Pear"`.  If "Pear" is found, 1 is returned, else 0.

```
SUMPRODUCT(arrayofvisiblecells , arrayofcellswithPear)
```

is used to sum all of the times when the cell is visible AND "Pear" is present. `1*1` else you will be multiplying by a `0`.

Comment: Nice function to check for hidden cells. What is the purpose of `+0` at the end though. `ISNUMBER` will return either TRUE or FALSE which I understand as 1 or 0. Is the `+0` so that Excel considers it as a number when doing the `SUMPRODUCT`?

Comment: @nbayly I'm unsure.  I found this code through a web search which is why I asked my original question.

Comment: I've confirmed that the formula doesn't work without the `+0`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @nbayly it is to change the True/False to 1/0.  It could also be `*1` or `--`.

Comment: @ScottCraner can you explain that last part "It could also be `*1` or `--`". Not sure I understand what you mean with the operators.

Comment: @nbayly `1` or `Nothing` becomes `1` or `0` with the `+0`

Comment: ISNUMBER() returns TRUE or FALSE. By using them in mathematical equations it reverts the text TRUE or FALSE to their Binary equivalents 1 or 0.  Adding 0, Multiplying by 1 or -1 * -1 reverts them to Binary.

Comment: you are correct that formula is not working, so the only shorter one I could come up with is this `=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(103,INDIRECT("B"&ROW($B$2:$B$17)))*($B$2:$B$17="Pear"))` it uses indirect which is still volatile, but it is a little shorter.

Comment: What is the danger of volatile?

Comment: If you have too many it will slow down the computation time overall, all volatile functions calculate every time, whether the data to which they refer has changed or not.  While non volatile only calculate when the data to which they refer is changed.  If this is the only one then it should not make a difference.  I usually avoid them unless necessary, which in this case appears to be the situation.

Answer (score 3):

With Office 365 we can finally get rid of the volatile OFFSET by using BYROW instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(BYROW(B2:B18,LAMBDA(a,SUBTOTAL(3,a))),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Pear",B2:B18))+0)
```

The `BYROW(B2:B18,LAMBDA(a,SUBTOTAL(3,a)))` does the same as `SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2:B18,ROW(B2:B18)-MIN(ROW(B2:B18)),,1))` without being volatile.

Answer (score -1):

=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1006,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1006)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1006)),,1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B861,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1006))+0)

B861 is what ever cell you are referencing.