# SUMIF only filtered data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have an excel formula that sums a particular column of data.

```
SUMIF(Data!$E:$E,$E$89,Data!$F:$F)
```

I'm looking to add a column G which I want to filter over. So, ideally, when I click Data->Filter, I can make SUMIF only sum whatever I filter in column G.

Is there a good way of doing so?

The data looks something like this:

```
E     F         G
111   20050719  Foreign
112   20050719  Domestic
576   20050719  Foreign
624   19910101  Domestic

$E$89 = 20050719
```

Comment: You will need to use SUBTOTAL with Offset or Indirect.  You can build off this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903731/countif-with-filtered-data

Answer (score 3):

The formula you want is taken and modified from this post; [CountIf With Filtered Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903731/countif-with-filtered-data)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(E2:E7,ROW($F$2:$F$7)-MIN(ROW($F$2:$F$7)),,1)),(E89=$F$2:$F$7)+0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe `SUMIF` etc have this functionality, however the `SUBTOTAL` function can do this.  (Another option using `SUMIFS` which allows for multiple conditions)

`=SUBTOTAL(9,Data_Range_To_Sum)`

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1

Comment: Subtotal does not include any filtered data.

Answer (score 0):

I am handling the same problem right know and I seem to have found a solution.

The screenshot shall be self explanatory - however the key is in placing the SUMIFS "subtotals" condition in the same column as the conditions in the data itself. The SUBTOTAL counts from the SUMIFS "subtotals" and all is filtered by the condidions.

[image]
[image]