# How to use COUNTIF with SUBTOTAL in this case?

Tags: excel, countif, subtotal

i have searched a lot, but nothing helps my case.

```
=SUMA((COUNTIF(List1!H:H; ""))+(COUNTIF(List1!H:H; "0"))+COUNTIF(List1!H:H; "#N/A")+(COUNTIF(List1!H:H; "-")))
```

How would you modify this code, so it doesn´t ignore filters? I tried a lot of things by combining it with SUBTOTAL, but it doesn´t work at all. :(

Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903731/countif-with-filtered-data)

Comment: I have a multiple conditions, which is problem i my case. I tried that one... Didn´t work.

Comment: please show how you tried to add the other conditions to that one.  It should be as simple as adding the conditions: `(H:H ="")+(H:H=0)+....` in the end of the formula linked.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is incorrect in the first place, it should be:

```
=SUM((COUNTIF(List1!H:H, ""))+(COUNTIF(List1!H:H, "0"))+COUNTIF(List1!H:H,"#N/A")+(COUNTIF(List1!H:H, "-")))
```

Can you upload your file to see exactly what you need to achieve?