# COUNTIF() with filters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I want to count all rows in an Excel table which contain "01.09.2019" in column "D".

First problem: The table is on another sheet

Second problem: Column "D" contains date AND time (e.g. 01.09.2019 00:45:20) but I'm only interested in the dates. I did this with:

`=COUNTIF(October_Data!$D$2:$D$299;"<02.09.2019")`

This works for me.
But now I want to filter the data and COUNTIF doesn't work with filters.

I found:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3;INDIRECT("D"&ROW(2:999)))*(D2:C999<"02.09.2019"))`

This obviously doesn't work because the hint to the data-sheet is missing but I really don't know where to use it. Besides of that I tried to rewrite the formula so it fits my needs but I don't really know if I made any mistakes because I have problems understanding the formula.

Here is an image for you: 
[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ30U.png)

The data is private so I had to make an example:

Column A is filtered by "a". Now I want to count every row which contains "01.09.2019". In this case it would only be one.
But remember: This table is part of the sheet "October_Data" and my calculations happen in another sheet!

Comment: Can you give a couple of lines to understand the data you need to get?

Comment: I just added a picture to my post. I hope this does help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903731/countif-with-filtered-data).  With the necessary modifications:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(October_Data!$D$2:$D$299,ROW(October_Data!$D$2:$D$299)-MIN(ROW(October_Data!$D$2:$D$299)),,1))*(October_Data!$D$2:$D$299<DATE(2019,9,2)))
```

With your local setting you will need to change the `,` for `;`

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't apply the formula, so I did some changes:

```=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3;OFFSET(October_Data!$D$2:$D$299,ROW(October_Data!$D$2:$D$299)-MIN(ROW(October_Data!$D$2:$D$299));1))*(D2:C999<"02.10.2019"))```

I don't know if this was right but now excel applies the formula. But it doesn't seem to work anyway :(

It Shows: #name

Comment: I missed a reference, see the edit.  Your local setting require that you change the `,` for `;`.  copy the new formula and change the `,` to `;` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! It almost seems to work. It now counts only the filtered rows but still all of them. I want excel to count only the rows with "01.10.2019" in column "D" (remember: Column D contains cells like "01.10.2019  06:43:24" but I need to ignore the time)

Comment: are your dates true dates and not a text string that looks like a date?  If you change the number format of the cell does the text change or remain the same?

Comment: The format was "custom". I changed to "date" but the result didn't chang. The text in the cells changed because the time is now no longer visible.

Comment: Then let us use DATE instead of a string, see edit.

Comment: Wow this helped! Now it works perfectly… Just being corious: I tried =DATE(…) instead of <DATE(…) but this doesn't work. Why is that a problem?

Comment: The cell has a time element so it will never equal an exact date.  You will need to use `<` or `>`