# Using IF with AGGREGATE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

While I am a longtime 'lurker' and have gleaned a great amount of Excel knowledge through this site, I've never asked a question before. This time I'm really stumped...

I have a table with multiple columns. The data I'm working with is obtained from a multiple VLOOKUPs of another workbook for which I do not own. That workbook has some issues with hidden characters and rows that are hidden. I'm trying to create a dashboard from this data and was successful using the AGGREGATE function (2,7) to COUNT and omit the data I don't want.

The next tier for this data needs to incorporate a lookup against another column (image attached). For this, I want to look up data in column B and subtract cells in column C if the data in column B matches a cell in column A.

I have tried multiple ways of doing this but I think that AGGREGATE might be the best approach since it can ignore hidden data and rows.

My latest attempt was to add an IF statement as follows, but that results in a SPILL condition:

```
=IF('Transport Calendar'!E2:E830='Transport Calcs'!M6,AGGREGATE(2,7,'Transport Calendar'!X2:X830)-AGGREGATE(2,7,'Transport Calendar'!Z2:Z830),"FALSE")
```

Any help would most certainly be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: AGGREGATE is not the formula for this.  If you want to conditionally count a range and skip hidden data, then see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903731/countif-with-filtered-data

Comment: You may want to consider using FILTER and instead of hiding data (manually) let them be part of the filter (dynamically). The solution above would be volatile and would probably slow down your report.