# Sum values(column C) based on unique value(column A) after filtering(column B)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I need some help creating a formula.
I have an excel file with 3 columns and I need to sum values of column C, based on the unique values of column A even if I filter something in column B.

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | A | 10 |
| AAA | A | 10 |
| BBB | B | 20 |
| BBB | B | 20 |
| CCC | C | 10 |
| DDD | D | 10 |
| DDD | D | 10 |
| EEE | A | 20 |

I achieved that using the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C8:C8/COUNTIF(A8:A8;A8:A8)))
```

Which gives me the result "70" but when I use filter in column B, the result is not updated.
E.G. if I filter column B and choose to bring me only the "A" the result should be "30", but it remains "70".

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance,
Elias

Comment: use countifs() or more likely sumifs() where you add the constraint of column B.

Comment: Hi Mike, I do not really know how to do what you suggest...

Answer (score 2):

If ms365 is applicable, try to utilize `SUBTOTAL()` nested within `MAP()`:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:C9,MAP(A2:A9,LAMBDA(x,SUBTOTAL(103,x))))))
```

---

**Option 1 for Excel 2016**: `SUBTOTAL()` in an helper column:

OP's using ms Excel 2016, therefor he could also just apply the `SUBTOTAL(103,<ref>)` to an helper column:

[image]

Formula in `D2` and dragged down:

```
=SUBTOTAL(103,B2)
```

Formula in `F1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C9/COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A2:A9))*D2:D9)
```

---

**Option 2 for Excel 2016**: Measure inside Power Pivot Table:

You could also apply a Power Pivot Table.

- Select a cell from given table and on the 'Power Pivot' tab click to 'Add to Data Model';
- If any pop-up opens, you can close this for now;
- On the 'Power Pivot' tab now click 'Measures'>'New Measure';
- On the window that opens, select the previously added table at the top, find a suitable name for your measure and use the following formula:

  `=SUMX(DISTINCT(Table1[Col A]),FIRSTNONBLANK(Table1[Col C],0))`
- Click 'OK', then go back to the 'Power Pivot' tab to click 'Manage';
- On the 'Home' tab now click to insert a PivotTable, choose a suitable place for the output;
- Set ColA to rows, ColB to Filter and your measure to Values;
- The output should look something like this:

[image]

Now instead of filtering your original data, filter cell `F1`. You still have the option to select multiple options there.

A more convoluted option perhaps.

Comment: Sir it is fascinating even i found when wrapping within `SUM()` it ignores `A2:B9` and takes in `C2:C9` but I still went ahead and used `TAKE()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately ms365 functions are not applicable in my MSoffice 2016 version...

Comment: @EliasLiappis, right, I've edited my answer to accomodate for that.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, both that answer is given (in a slightly different form) and I find an helper column a better fit here.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, agree with you, helper will be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way without using any `LAMBDA()` helper function(`Applicable to MS365 exclusively`):

Before:

[image]

---

After:

[image]

---

```
=LET(α, A2:C9, SUM(TAKE(UNIQUE(FILTER(α,SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(α,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α))-1,0,1)))),,-1)))
```

---

For **Excel 2016** one can use the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
  IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($A$2:$C$9,ROW($A$2:$C$9)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$C$9)),,1)),
  C2:C9/COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9,B2:B9)))
```

---

Comment: Looking at OP's comment on JdVd's answer, `FILTER` is also post excel 2016, right? (same as `LET`, I believe but LET came a little later)

Comment: @Notus_Panda before posting answer there was no `Excel 2016` tag, while sir posted I was writing my answer. Please see **Edit** times it will help

Comment: Nono, I'm fully aware OP said that (too) late, was just confirming/keeping you up2date that OP has an older Excel and cannot use your current formula.

Comment: @Notus_Panda yes I know, but they should mention that in post. Thank you very much bro!

Comment: Guys it was my fault, not stating the version and the system I use...I am really sorry about that...

Comment: @EliasLiappis just posted an alternative solution for your version of `Excel 2016` let me know if that works

Answer (score 2):

Using this as a base:  [CountIf With Filtered Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903731/countif-with-filtered-data).

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$9=$A12)*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($C$2:$C$9,ROW($C$2:$C$9)-MIN(ROW($C$2:$C$9)),,1)))*$C$2:$C$9)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: BTW it needs to be distinct sum value and not just based on filtered list. Presently it captures only sum based on visible cells and not sum based on distinct filtered cells.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Is that the "based on the unique values of column A" bit in the question?  I'm not sure, but can definitely be read that way.

Comment: What output do you get `30` or `40`? that will explain the rest

Answer (score 1):

My joy was too hasty since `SEQUENCE` is also W365..
While I was trying to take Mayukh's formula apart bit by bit and getting stumped as to why `=SUBTOTAL(3;OFFSET(A2:C9;SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:C9))-1;0;1))` gave me a visible understanding but `OFFSET(A2:C9;SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:C9))-1;0;1)` just gave me a series of `#VALUE!` errors, I did realize I could maybe use the SUBTOTAL part and shove it into OP's formula.

It went rather well, formula in G1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C9*(SUBTOTAL(3;OFFSET(A2:C9;SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:C9))-1;0;1))>0)/COUNTIF(A2:A9;A2:A9))
```

[image]

Formula in F1 is Mayukh's formula and the rest below were some testing I previously mentioned.

Comment: [SEQUENCE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) is 365 - needs to be Excel 2016.

Comment: Dang nabbit, here I thought I had it. I'll mention it in the answer. Thanks ^^

Comment: I was going to say, saw @DarrenBartrup-Cook has already informed.

Comment: Think if I wanted to age the formula properly, I'd just end up with a similar formula to yours, right? @DarrenBartrup-Cook

Comment: @Notus_Panda.  Yes, I think it would be.

Comment: `SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:C9))-1` can be replaced with `ROW(A2:C9)-2` which produces the same array. Only downside is that if a user deletes any of the cells in or prior to range `A2:C9` it can change the size/start value.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as with the SEQUENCE part? Thanks for the tip btw :)

Comment: I saw the mention of SEQUENCE not being compatible. Using my suggestion (entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` ) allows a sequence alternative for older Excel versions.

Comment: I meant the part where deleting cells would be an issue @P.b

Comment: You're right in this case, since we use a range as an argument in SEQUENCE as well. Just something to be aware of when using it like this, because it may turn out to become unpredictable.